# How to handle the "Cancel" event of the "Welcome.nsh" file in my "TestSetup.nsi" file using NSIS

Tags: nsis

My requirement is when installing the NSIS installer, if the user has cancelled the installation process in the "Welcome" screen by clicking on the "Cancel" button it should pop-up a message "Are you sure you want to cancel the installation" with "yes" and "no" buttons. And here when clicked on "yes", the installation should be interrupted and go the "installation interrupt" screen.

But here, Welcome.nsh file is there in the path (\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\Pages\Welcome.nsh). So how to handle the "Cancel" event of the "Welcome.nsh" file in my "TestSetup.nsi" file?

**Updated code Based on the inputs:**

```
;Include Modern UI

Var IsOnWelcomePage
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT onAbort

!include "MUI2.nsh"

; Request application privileges for Windows Vista
; Below line is to check the administrative permissions
RequestExecutionLevel admin

; Below is the include file to check the conditions (If and else)
!include LogicLib.nsh
;--------------------------------

; Pages

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW WelShow
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE WelLeave

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  ;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
;--------------------------------

;Languages

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "PortugueseBR"
  ; Below is to remove the label NULLsoft installer from the installer screens
  BrandingText " "
;--------------------------------
;Installer Functions


;--------------------------------
; The stuff to install

Function WelShow
StrCpy $IsOnWelcomePage 1
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 3
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide Back button
FunctionEnd

Function WelLeave
StrCpy $IsOnWelcomePage 0
FunctionEnd

Function MySillyPage
${IfThen} $IsOnWelcomePage == "" ${|} Abort ${|}
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide Next button
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 2
${NSD_SetText} $0 "$(^CloseBtn)"
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "EMR" "EMR Setup Wizard was interrupted"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "EMR Setup Wizard was interrupted. $\r$\n$\r$\n Click the finish button to exit the Setup Wizard"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function onAbort
${If} $IsOnWelcomePage <> 0
    ${If} ${Cmd} ` MessageBox MB_YESNO "Are you sure you want to cancel EMR installation?" IDYES `
        Call WelLeave
        SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 -1 ""
    ${EndIf}
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section "RegistryTest (required)"

SectionIn RO

  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  
....

SectionEnd
```

Comment: What is the "installation interrupt" screen?

Comment: Not including important stuff like that makes it harder to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you think you need this functionality but here you go:

```
Var IsOnWelcomePage
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT onAbort
!include MUI2.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom MySillyPage
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW WelShow
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE WelLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function WelShow
StrCpy $IsOnWelcomePage 1
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 3
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide Back button
FunctionEnd

Function WelLeave
StrCpy $IsOnWelcomePage 0
FunctionEnd

Function MySillyPage
${IfThen} $IsOnWelcomePage == "" ${|} Abort ${|}
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide Next button
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 2
${NSD_SetText} $0 "$(^CloseBtn)"
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah" "Blah blah"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Blah blah blah"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function onAbort
${If} $IsOnWelcomePage <> 0
    ${If} ${Cmd} ` MessageBox MB_YESNO "Sure?" IDYES `
        Call WelLeave
        SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 -1 ""
    ${EndIf}
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

and if you want this behavior on multiple pages:

```
Var PageId
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT onAbort
!include MUI2.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom MySillyPage
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW WelShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW DirShow ; Could use Pre callback instead if needed
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function WelShow
StrCpy $PageId 1
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 3
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide Back button
FunctionEnd

Function DirShow
StrCpy $PageId 2
FunctionEnd


Function MySillyPage
${IfThen} $PageId == "" ${|} Abort ${|}
StrCpy $PageId 0
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
ShowWindow $0 0 ; Hide Next button
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 2
${NSD_SetText} $0 "$(^CloseBtn)"
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah" "Blah blah"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Blah blah blah"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function onAbort
${If} $PageId <> 0
    ${If} ${Cmd} ` MessageBox MB_YESNO "Sure?" IDYES `
        SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 -$PageId ""
    ${EndIf}
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: You did not copy the `Page Custom MySillyPage` line!

Comment: Yes you said in your question you only wanted it on the Welcome screen. Comment out the line in WelLeave, that might make it work on all pages.

Comment: Each page needs a show callback where you change a variable to a number and you must replace `-1` with this variable in the message you send in the abort function. I will try to update my answer soon.